# Creating Git branch tag in VSO or VS2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Is there a way to create a branch tag in vso?

Also, I've tried creating a tag in VS2015 and push a change commit to vso, but I'm not seeing the tag in vso. Just wondering if this VS2015 <-> VSO tagging feature is in place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tag you created in VS2015 is in local repository. VS2015 cannot push the tag to remote repository for now. You need to push the tags to remote repository by following command manually:

```
git push --tags
```

After executing this command, you will see the tags in VSO.
[image]

Comment: I'm using this manual method currently too. I'm just surprise that no one requested this feature in the VS uservoice website.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 with VSTS and it still seems that they haven't added support for this yet? (can create Tag in VS, just can't push it in VS) :o/

Comment: Having pushed a tag to the remote repository, is there a way to see it within visualstudio.com?

Comment: Sorry I was meaning in VSO - but just realised thats the screenshot you originally posted, and there they are :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it wasn't available in Visual Studio 2015, but in Visual Studio 2017, I've created tags by right-clicking on the commits when viewing the history of a branch.

I didn't realize they weren't pushed with `Sync`. So I just recently found you need to access the `Tags` menu and hit `Push All` to push the tags to the remote repository:

[image: VS2017 Tags Git window]

And [Eddie Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33793973/1380710) obviously still works too in VS2017.

Answer (score -1):

Just looking into this for myself.  We found the label feature that I think does the same thing.  Right click on the branch in the source control explorer, go to advanced, apply label. Hope this works.  Not sure if it's what you're after, but we're going to try it.

Comment: that is when you're using TFVC, not with Git.