# Is it possible to create Git branch tags in Visual Studio Team Services directly?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

Is it possible to create a Git branch tag in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) directly? I have [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787890/creating-git-branch-tag-in-vso-or-vs2015/33791641) that you can do so with Visual Studio in your local repo and then push it online but I'm interested in doing so without having to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t that feature of creating a git branch tag to Visual Studio Team Services directly. You can vote this user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15927541-vsts-create-add-git-branch-tag-on-web-access.